# How to read 火日参拾月参

Tags: translation

I'm trying to figure out on how to read this properly

> 火日参拾月参

[image]

The translation is supposed to be

> Monday, March 13th

Now maybe it's because I'm still confused on what the correct reading direction is (left-to-right or righ-to-left), but I still don't understand why it's supposed to be "**Monday**".

I (think I) do know the following

> 月参 = month 3 = March
>
> 参拾 = 3 1 = 13

But then I'm left with

> 火日 = ?

I tried looking up just the days of the week...

> 火曜日 = Tuesday ; 月曜日 = Monday

...but that confused me even further.

Comment: It was from official translations, both Crunchyroll and BD. Guess they can make mistakes as well ;S

Comment: They are absolutely full of mistakes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it's written [right-to-left](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13076/5010). After changing the direction, it's:

> 参月 拾参日 火

Or:

> 三月 十三日 火

Which reads "March", "**13th** (day of month)", "**Tuesday**", respectively. Perhaps the translator was also confused :)

As you probably know, the standard format of dates in Japanese is `month 月 day 日`, optionally followed by the day of the week. For example, today is "2月28日(木)".

Comment: 右から読むのね～ってそらそうか・・

Comment: @naruto Thank you for your answer and the additional information. I already had a hunch that it was supposed to be _tuesday_ (because of the *火*)  but I didn't really want to think that the official translations were wrong.